# Page Weight check for GA integration

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

**Looking for a way to check Page weight with a JS script? or maybe GTM?**

looking for a solution that will allow me to integrate results with **Google Analytics**.

I checked the `scripts` that appear in v`arious threads`, but their operation `counting HTML characters` and dividing them later gives only a `fraction` of the `value` I understand by page weight.

I also want to collect information about the **weight of images, scripts, etc**.

**Do you think you could help?**

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can iterate over all source attributes in your page, then do an ajax request for each value and look into the content length header in the response headers. The obvious caveat is that this would add a lot of requests to your page, which is rather undesirable. Also there is a good chance that many people would leave before the operation is complete, so you might get unreliable values.

Clearly, this is not the way to go. Client side Javascript is not well equipped for this task.

However, unless your pages are weirdly configurable per user, page weight will be approximately the same on each url call. Rather than doing that it the browser, I would recommend you set up a headless browser (something like [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/), or e.g. [saucelabs](https://saucelabs.com/sign-up?campid=7011M0000013Rl0&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_eSkufur6gIVkOd3Ch1NywroEAAYASAAEgL1BvD_BwE) if you want a prefconfigured service; you need something that executes Javascript, since dynamic loading might change page weight), run it once per week or so on every url, and then do a hit level [data import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191589) in Google Analytics. On a free Analytics account, this will not add to already existing data, but for all newly incoming hits the import could add the page size to every url.